What's the best way to create a unit test to check if a form submission is successfull? (next.js and jest)
I'm currently developing a unit test for a registration form in my application. The test should verify that the registration process completes successfully without storing new data in the actual database.
Here's a simplified version of how my registration form and action work: Upon form submission, the registerAction function is invoked, which sanitizes the input data, validates it against a schema using Zod, checks if the email already exists in the database, hashes the password, and finally attempts to create a new user record in the database using Prisma.
During testing, I want to simulate a successful registration without modifying the database. What are the recommended strategies or best practices to achieve this goal?
register-form.tsx
"use client";

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { FormSchema } from "@/schemas/FormSchema";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { z } from "zod";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Form, FormControl, FormDescription, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormMessage } from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Card, CardContent, CardDescription, CardHeader, CardTitle } from "@/components/ui/card";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { useToast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast"

import { registerAction } from "@/actions/registerAction";

export function RegisterForm() {
  const { toast } = useToast()
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      passwordConfirmation: "",
    },
  });

  async function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) {
    try {
      const result = await registerAction(data);

      if (!result.success) {
        toast({
          title: "Error",
          description: result.message
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Card className="max-w-sm w-full">
      <CardHeader>
        <CardTitle>Register</CardTitle>
        <CardDescription>Enter your information to create an account.</CardDescription>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardContent>
        <Form {...form}>
          <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-6">
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="email"
              type="email"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="password"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input {...field} type="password" />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="passwordConfirmation"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Password Confirmation</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input {...field} type="password" />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <Button type="submit" className="w-full">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Form>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}

register-form.test.tsx
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { RegisterForm } from './register-form'

describe('RegisterForm', () => {
  test('submits form with valid data', async () => {

    render(<RegisterForm />);

    // Fill in form fields
    const emailInput = screen.getByLabelText('Email');
    const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText('Password');
    const passwordConfirmationInput = screen.getByLabelText('Password Confirmation');

    userEvent.type(emailInput, 'test@example.com');
    userEvent.type(passwordInput, 'password123');
    userEvent.type(passwordConfirmationInput, 'password123');

    const submitButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Submit' });
    fireEvent.click(submitButton);
    
  });
});

registerAction.ts
"use server";

import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { z } from "zod";
import { FormSchema } from "@/schemas/FormSchema";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

function sanitizeData(data: { email: string; password: string; passwordConfirmation: string }): {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  passwordConfirmation: string;
} {
  const sanitizedData = {
    email: data.email.trim().toLowerCase(),
    password: data.password.trim(),
    passwordConfirmation: data.passwordConfirmation.trim(),
  };

  return sanitizedData;
}

async function emailExists(email: string) {
  try {
    const user = await prisma.users.findUnique({
      where: {
        email: email,
      },
    });

    if (user) {
      return true;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

async function validateData(data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) {
  const validation = FormSchema.safeParse({
    email: data.email,
    password: data.password,
    passwordConfirmation: data.passwordConfirmation,
  });

  if (!validation.success) {
    return validation.error.errors;
  }
}

export const registerAction = async (data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) => {
  try {
    const sanitizedData = sanitizeData(data);

    const validationErrors = await validateData(sanitizedData);
    if (validationErrors) {
      return {
        success: false,
        message: "Validation errors",
        errors: validationErrors,
      };
    }

    const emailAlreadyExist = await emailExists(sanitizedData.email);
    if (emailAlreadyExist) {
      return {
        success: false,
        message: "Email already exists",
      };
    }

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(sanitizedData.password, 10);
    sanitizedData.password = hashedPassword;

    await prisma.users.create({
      data: {
        email: sanitizedData.email,
        password: sanitizedData.password,
      },
    });

    return {
      success: true,
      message: "User created"
    };

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  redirect("/login");
};


I guess you should be able to mock the module:
jest.mock('@/actions/registerAction', () => ({
  registerAction: jest.fn()
  // could be also jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
}));

and then in the test you assert if the mock function was called as you expect.
